# Mongodb: mmap private failed with out of memory. (64 bit build)

Tags: mongodb

Mongo seems to have run out of memory!? What can I do?

I am not even sure it's actually a memory problem.

```
2016-08-11T14:23:26.875+0200 E CONTROL  [conn2575] mmap private failed with out of memory. (64 bit build)
2016-08-11T14:23:26.875+0200 I -        [conn2575] Assertion: 13636:file /data/db/project.6 open/create failed in createPrivateMap (look in log for more information)
2016-08-11T14:23:26.892+0200 I CONTROL  [conn2575]
 0xf9b632 0xf36699 0xf1a22e 0xf1a2dc 0xd56925 0xd56b5f 0xd3cf06 0xd6ff6d 0xd70380 0xd7061d 0xd74ec2 0xd80b34 0xd756ab 0xd75859 0x90a811 0x90b3ec 0xa3e5fc 0xa3f334 0xbe8012 0xbe832b 0xbe8a0d 0x9b1769 0x9b2fc5 0x9b35f5 0x9b62dc 0x9d9071 0x9da07c 0x9dad4b 0xbb544b 0xac3e4a 0x7fd9c5 0xf4af79 0x7f9122c60aa1 0x7f91217b293d
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
{"backtrace":[{"b":"400000","o":"B9B632","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo"},{"b":"400000","o":"B36699","s":"_ZN5mongo10logContextEPKc"},{"b":"400000","o":"B1A22E","s":"_ZN5mongo11msgassertedEiPKc"},{"b":"400000","o":"B1A2DC"},{"b":"400000","o":"956925","s":"_ZN5mongo17DurableMappedFile13finishOpeningEv"},{"b":"400000","o":"956B5F","s":"_ZN5mongo17DurableMappedFile6createERKSsRyb"},{"b":"400000","o":"93CF06","s":"_ZN5mongo8DataFile4openEPNS_16OperationContextEPKcib"},{"b":"400000","o":"96FF6D","s":"_ZN5mongo19MmapV1ExtentManager9_addAFileEPNS_16OperationContextEib"},{"b":"400000","o":"970380","s":"_ZN5mongo19MmapV1ExtentManager13_createExtentEPNS_16OperationContextEib"},{"b":"400000","o":"97061D","s":"_ZN5mongo19MmapV1ExtentManager14allocateExtentEPNS_16OperationContextEbib"},{"b":"400000","o":"974EC2","s":"_ZN5mongo17RecordStoreV1Base19increaseStorageSizeEPNS_16OperationContextEib"},{"b":"400000","o":"980B34","s":"_ZN5mongo19SimpleRecordStoreV111allocRecordEPNS_16OperationContextEib"},{"b":"400000","o":"9756AB","s":"_ZN5mongo17RecordStoreV1Base13_insertRecordEPNS_16OperationContextEPKcib"},{"b":"400000","o":"975859","s":"_ZN5mongo17RecordStoreV1Base12insertRecordEPNS_16OperationContextEPKcib"},{"b":"400000","o":"50A811","s":"_ZN5mongo10Collection15_insertDocumentEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_7BSONObjEb"},{"b":"400000","o":"50B3EC","s":"_ZN5mongo10Collection14insertDocumentEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_7BSONObjEb"},{"b":"400000","o":"63E5FC","s":"_ZN5mongo11UpdateStage8doInsertEv"},{"b":"400000","o":"63F334","s":"_ZN5mongo11UpdateStage4workEPm"},{"b":"400000","o":"7E8012","s":"_ZN5mongo12PlanExecutor18getNextSnapshottedEPNS_11SnapshottedINS_7BSONObjEEEPNS_8RecordIdE"},{"b":"400000","o":"7E832B","s":"_ZN5mongo12PlanExecutor7getNextEPNS_7BSONObjEPNS_8RecordIdE"},{"b":"400000","o":"7E8A0D","s":"_ZN5mongo12PlanExecutor11executePlanEv"},{"b":"400000","o":"5B1769","s":"_ZN5mongo18WriteBatchExecutor10execUpdateERKNS_12BatchItemRefEPNS_7BSONObjEPPNS_16WriteErrorDetailE"},{"b":"400000","o":"5B2FC5","s":"_ZN5mongo18WriteBatchExecutor11bulkExecuteERKNS_21BatchedCommandRequestERKNS_19WriteConcernOptionsEPSt6vectorIPNS_19BatchedUpsertDetailESaIS9_EEPS7_IPNS_16WriteErrorDetailESaISE_EE"},{"b":"400000","o":"5B35F5","s":"_ZN5mongo18WriteBatchExecutor12executeBatchERKNS_21BatchedCommandRequestEPNS_22BatchedCommandResponseE"},{"b":"400000","o":"5B62DC","s":"_ZN5mongo8WriteCmd3runEPNS_16OperationContextERKSsRNS_7BSONObjEiRSsRNS_14BSONObjBuilderEb"},{"b":"400000","o":"5D9071","s":"_ZN5mongo12_execCommandEPNS_16OperationContextEPNS_7CommandERKSsRNS_7BSONObjEiRSsRNS_14BSONObjBuilderEb"},{"b":"400000","o":"5DA07C","s":"_ZN5mongo7Command11execCommandEPNS_16OperationContextEPS0_iPKcRNS_7BSONObjERNS_14BSONObjBuilderEb"},{"b":"400000","o":"5DAD4B","s":"_ZN5mongo12_runCommandsEPNS_16OperationContextEPKcRNS_7BSONObjERNS_11_BufBuilderINS_16TrivialAllocatorEEERNS_14BSONObjBuilderEbi"},{"b":"400000","o":"7B544B","s":"_ZN5mongo8runQueryEPNS_16OperationContextERNS_7MessageERNS_12QueryMessageERKNS_15NamespaceStringERNS_5CurOpES3_"},{"b":"400000","o":"6C3E4A","s":"_ZN5mongo16assembleResponseEPNS_16OperationContextERNS_7MessageERNS_10DbResponseERKNS_11HostAndPortE"},{"b":"400000","o":"3FD9C5","s":"_ZN5mongo16MyMessageHandler7processERNS_7MessageEPNS_21AbstractMessagingPortEPNS_9LastErrorE"},{"b":"400000","o":"B4AF79","s":"_ZN5mongo17PortMessageServer17handleIncomingMsgEPv"},{"b":"7F9122C59000","o":"7AA1"},{"b":"7F91216CA000","o":"E893D","s":"clone"}],"processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "3.0.9", "gitVersion" : "20d60d3491908f1ae252fe452300de3978a040c7", "uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "2.6.32-042stab113.11", "version" : "#1 SMP Fri Dec 18 17:32:04 MSK 2015", "machine" : "x86_64" }, "somap" : [ { "elfType" : 2, "b" : "400000", "buildId" : "47DFD0896283C6BF009395E08B673D3246CC7AE5" }, { "b" : "7FFD9BE1E000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "F466F3FAB4F73E9911206E2486A3C5F8FCCA8EA5" }, { "b" : "7F9122C59000", "path" : "/lib64/libpthread.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "C56DD1B811FC0D9263248EBB308C73FCBCD80FC1" }, { "b" : "7F91229ED000", "path" : "/usr/lib64/libssl.so.10", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "24A4E7055CABC29C2DDAC730D635A20C08687AC6" }, { "b" : "7F912260A000", "path" : "/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "F6F5BB27A852F29A134680794DD2EB5C3CC5D88B" }, { "b" : "7F9122402000", "path" : "/lib64/librt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "95159178F1A4A3DBDC7819FBEA2C80E5FCDD6BAC" }, { "b" : "7F91221FE000", "path" : "/lib64/libdl.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "29B61382141595ECBA6576232E44F2310C3AAB72" }, { "b" : "7F9121EF8000", "path" : "/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "C03877A9EE01DDC572E2B0F55F64C757773CF8D6" }, { "b" : "7F9121C74000", "path" : "/lib64/libm.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "989FE3A42CA8CEBDCC185A743896F23A0CF537ED" }, { "b" : "7F9121A5E000", "path" : "/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "9350579A4970FA47F3144AD8F40B183B0954497D" }, { "b" : "7F91216CA000", "path" : "/lib64/libc.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "8E6FA4C4B0594C355C1B90C1D49990368C81A040" }, { "b" : "7F9122E76000", "path" : "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "959C5E10A47EE8A633E7681B64B4B9F74E242ED5" }, { "b" : "7F9121486000", "path" : "/lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "441FA45097A11508E50D55A3D1FF169BF2BE7C62" }, { "b" : "7F912119F000", "path" : "/lib64/libkrb5.so.3", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "F62622218875795666E08B92D176A50791183EEC" }, { "b" : "7F9120F9B000", "path" : "/lib64/libcom_err.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "152E2C18A7A2145021A8A879A01A82EE134E3946" }, { "b" : "7F9120D6F000", "path" : "/lib64/libk5crypto.so.3", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "B8DEDADC140347276164C729418C7A37B7224135" }, { "b" : "7F9120B59000", "path" : "/lib64/libz.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "5FA8E5038EC04A774AF72A9BB62DC86E1049C4D6" }, { "b" : "7F912094E000", "path" : "/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "4BDFC7A19C1F328EB4FCFBCE7A1E27606928610D" }, { "b" : "7F912074B000", "path" : "/lib64/libkeyutils.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "AF374BAFB7F5B139A0B431D3F06D82014AFF3251" }, { "b" : "7F9120531000", "path" : "/lib64/libresolv.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "C39D7FFB49DFB1B55AD09D1D711AD802123F6623" }, { "b" : "7F9120312000", "path" : "/lib64/libselinux.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "E6798A06BEE17CF102BBA44FD512FF8B805CEAF1" } ] }}
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x32) [0xf9b632]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10logContextEPKc+0xE9) [0xf36699]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo11msgassertedEiPKc+0xAE) [0xf1a22e]
 mongod(+0xB1A2DC) [0xf1a2dc]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo17DurableMappedFile13finishOpeningEv+0x2F5) [0xd56925]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo17DurableMappedFile6createERKSsRyb+0x6F) [0xd56b5f]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo8DataFile4openEPNS_16OperationContextEPKcib+0x106) [0xd3cf06]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo19MmapV1ExtentManager9_addAFileEPNS_16OperationContextEib+0x15D) [0xd6ff6d]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo19MmapV1ExtentManager13_createExtentEPNS_16OperationContextEib+0xE0) [0xd70380]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo19MmapV1ExtentManager14allocateExtentEPNS_16OperationContextEbib+0x1FD) [0xd7061d]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo17RecordStoreV1Base19increaseStorageSizeEPNS_16OperationContextEib+0x42) [0xd74ec2]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo19SimpleRecordStoreV111allocRecordEPNS_16OperationContextEib+0x1F4) [0xd80b34]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo17RecordStoreV1Base13_insertRecordEPNS_16OperationContextEPKcib+0x5B) [0xd756ab]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo17RecordStoreV1Base12insertRecordEPNS_16OperationContextEPKcib+0x79) [0xd75859]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10Collection15_insertDocumentEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_7BSONObjEb+0x61) [0x90a811]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10Collection14insertDocumentEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_7BSONObjEb+0x8C) [0x90b3ec]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo11UpdateStage8doInsertEv+0x17C) [0xa3e5fc]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo11UpdateStage4workEPm+0xD4) [0xa3f334]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12PlanExecutor18getNextSnapshottedEPNS_11SnapshottedINS_7BSONObjEEEPNS_8RecordIdE+0x142) [0xbe8012]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12PlanExecutor7getNextEPNS_7BSONObjEPNS_8RecordIdE+0x3B) [0xbe832b]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12PlanExecutor11executePlanEv+0x3D) [0xbe8a0d]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo18WriteBatchExecutor10execUpdateERKNS_12BatchItemRefEPNS_7BSONObjEPPNS_16WriteErrorDetailE+0x719) [0x9b1769]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo18WriteBatchExecutor11bulkExecuteERKNS_21BatchedCommandRequestERKNS_19WriteConcernOptionsEPSt6vectorIPNS_19BatchedUpsertDetailESaIS9_EEPS7_IPNS_16WriteErrorDetailESaISE_EE+0x245) [0x9b2fc5]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo18WriteBatchExecutor12executeBatchERKNS_21BatchedCommandRequestEPNS_22BatchedCommandResponseE+0x465) [0x9b35f5]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo8WriteCmd3runEPNS_16OperationContextERKSsRNS_7BSONObjEiRSsRNS_14BSONObjBuilderEb+0x17C) [0x9b62dc]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12_execCommandEPNS_16OperationContextEPNS_7CommandERKSsRNS_7BSONObjEiRSsRNS_14BSONObjBuilderEb+0x31) [0x9d9071]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo7Command11execCommandEPNS_16OperationContextEPS0_iPKcRNS_7BSONObjERNS_14BSONObjBuilderEb+0xC6C) [0x9da07c]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12_runCommandsEPNS_16OperationContextEPKcRNS_7BSONObjERNS_11_BufBuilderINS_16TrivialAllocatorEEERNS_14BSONObjBuilderEbi+0x28B) [0x9dad4b]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo8runQueryEPNS_16OperationContextERNS_7MessageERNS_12QueryMessageERKNS_15NamespaceStringERNS_5CurOpES3_+0x73B) [0xbb544b]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo16assembleResponseEPNS_16OperationContextERNS_7MessageERNS_10DbResponseERKNS_11HostAndPortE+0xABA) [0xac3e4a]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo16MyMessageHandler7processERNS_7MessageEPNS_21AbstractMessagingPortEPNS_9LastErrorE+0xF5) [0x7fd9c5]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo17PortMessageServer17handleIncomingMsgEPv+0x339) [0xf4af79]
 libpthread.so.0(+0x7AA1) [0x7f9122c60aa1]
 libc.so.6(clone+0x6D) [0x7f91217b293d]
-----  END BACKTRACE  -----
```

ulimit -a

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 127948
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 127948
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

ulimit -v

```
unlimited
```

swapon -s

```
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/dev/null                               partition       524288  175344  -1
```

free -m

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          4096       3331        764         15          0       2985
-/+ buffers/cache:        345       3750
Swap:          512        171        340
```

df -h

```
Filesystem         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/ploop10759p1   40G   26G   12G  69% /
none                16G  4.0K   16G   1% /dev
none                16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm

# cat /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
0
```

ps aux | grep mongo

```
webdev    4006  0.2 26.0 9123780 1091292 ?     Sl   14:54   0:06 mongod --logpath /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
webdev    6031  0.0  0.0 103312   872 pts/1    S+   15:35   0:00 grep mongo
```

mongod --version

```
db version v3.0.12
git version: 33934938e0e95d534cebbaff656cde916b9c3573
```

cat /etc/centos-release

```
CentOS release 6.8 (Final)
```

db.serverStatus()

```
{
    "host" : "host",
    "version" : "3.0.12",
    "process" : "mongod",
    "pid" : NumberLong(4006),
    "uptime" : 3590,
    "uptimeMillis" : NumberLong(3590668),
    "uptimeEstimate" : 3555,
    "localTime" : ISODate("2016-08-11T13:54:51.869Z"),
    "asserts" : {
        "regular" : 0,
        "warning" : 1,
        "msg" : 0,
        "user" : 0,
        "rollovers" : 0
    },
    "backgroundFlushing" : {
        "flushes" : 59,
        "total_ms" : 80,
        "average_ms" : 1.3559322033898304,
        "last_ms" : 1,
        "last_finished" : ISODate("2016-08-11T13:54:01.250Z")
    },
    "connections" : {
        "current" : 4,
        "available" : 815,
        "totalCreated" : NumberLong(6)
    },
    "cursors" : {
        "note" : "deprecated, use server status metrics",
        "clientCursors_size" : 0,
        "totalOpen" : 0,
        "pinned" : 0,
        "totalNoTimeout" : 0,
        "timedOut" : 0
    },
    "dur" : {
        "commits" : 24,
        "journaledMB" : 0,
        "writeToDataFilesMB" : 0,
        "compression" : 0,
        "commitsInWriteLock" : 0,
        "earlyCommits" : 0,
        "timeMs" : {
            "dt" : 0,
            "prepLogBuffer" : 0,
            "writeToJournal" : 0,
            "writeToDataFiles" : 0,
            "remapPrivateView" : 0,
            "commits" : 0,
            "commitsInWriteLock" : 0
        }
    },
    "extra_info" : {
        "note" : "fields vary by platform",
        "heap_usage_bytes" : 63466248,
        "page_faults" : 28
    },
    "globalLock" : {
        "totalTime" : NumberLong("3590669000"),
        "currentQueue" : {
            "total" : 0,
            "readers" : 0,
            "writers" : 0
        },
        "activeClients" : {
            "total" : 12,
            "readers" : 0,
            "writers" : 0
        }
    },
    "locks" : {
        "Global" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(47395),
                "w" : NumberLong(1270),
                "W" : NumberLong(5)
            },
            "acquireWaitCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(1)
            },
            "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(641)
            }
        },
        "MMAPV1Journal" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(23058),
                "w" : NumberLong(1300),
                "R" : NumberLong(35093)
            },
            "acquireWaitCount" : {
                "w" : NumberLong(3),
                "R" : NumberLong(3)
            },
            "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                "w" : NumberLong(24),
                "R" : NumberLong(63215)
            }
        },
        "Database" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(23056),
                "w" : NumberLong(1247),
                "R" : NumberLong(4),
                "W" : NumberLong(23)
            }
        },
        "Collection" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "R" : NumberLong(24059),
                "W" : NumberLong(1247)
            }
        },
        "Metadata" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "W" : NumberLong(1)
            }
        }
    },
    "network" : {
        "bytesIn" : NumberLong(28574),
        "bytesOut" : NumberLong(14793714),
        "numRequests" : NumberLong(229)
    },
    "opcounters" : {
        "insert" : 0,
        "query" : 216,
        "update" : 1,
        "delete" : 0,
        "getmore" : 3,
        "command" : 11
    },
    "opcountersRepl" : {
        "insert" : 0,
        "query" : 0,
        "update" : 0,
        "delete" : 0,
        "getmore" : 0,
        "command" : 0
    },
    "storageEngine" : {
        "name" : "mmapv1"
    },
    "writeBacksQueued" : false,
    "mem" : {
        "bits" : 64,
        "resident" : 1068,
        "virtual" : 8909,
        "supported" : true,
        "mapped" : 4287,
        "mappedWithJournal" : 8574
    },
    "metrics" : {
        "commands" : {
            "getLog" : {
                "failed" : NumberLong(0),
                "total" : NumberLong(1)
            },
            "isMaster" : {
                "failed" : NumberLong(0),
                "total" : NumberLong(5)
            },
            "replSetGetStatus" : {
                "failed" : NumberLong(1),
                "total" : NumberLong(1)
            },
            "serverStatus" : {
                "failed" : NumberLong(0),
                "total" : NumberLong(2)
            },
            "update" : {
                "failed" : NumberLong(0),
                "total" : NumberLong(1)
            },
            "whatsmyuri" : {
                "failed" : NumberLong(0),
                "total" : NumberLong(2)
            }
        },
        "cursor" : {
            "timedOut" : NumberLong(0),
            "open" : {
                "noTimeout" : NumberLong(0),
                "pinned" : NumberLong(0),
                "total" : NumberLong(0)
            }
        },
        "document" : {
            "deleted" : NumberLong(0),
            "inserted" : NumberLong(0),
            "returned" : NumberLong(26915),
            "updated" : NumberLong(0)
        },
        "getLastError" : {
            "wtime" : {
                "num" : 0,
                "totalMillis" : 0
            },
            "wtimeouts" : NumberLong(0)
        },
        "operation" : {
            "fastmod" : NumberLong(0),
            "idhack" : NumberLong(0),
            "scanAndOrder" : NumberLong(140),
            "writeConflicts" : NumberLong(0)
        },
        "queryExecutor" : {
            "scanned" : NumberLong(599),
            "scannedObjects" : NumberLong(439045)
        },
        "record" : {
            "moves" : NumberLong(0)
        },
        "repl" : {
            "apply" : {
                "batches" : {
                    "num" : 0,
                    "totalMillis" : 0
                },
                "ops" : NumberLong(0)
            },
            "buffer" : {
                "count" : NumberLong(0),
                "maxSizeBytes" : 268435456,
                "sizeBytes" : NumberLong(0)
            },
            "network" : {
                "bytes" : NumberLong(0),
                "getmores" : {
                    "num" : 0,
                    "totalMillis" : 0
                },
                "ops" : NumberLong(0),
                "readersCreated" : NumberLong(0)
            },
            "preload" : {
                "docs" : {
                    "num" : 0,
                    "totalMillis" : 0
                },
                "indexes" : {
                    "num" : 0,
                    "totalMillis" : 0
                }
            }
        },
        "storage" : {
            "freelist" : {
                "search" : {
                    "bucketExhausted" : NumberLong(0),
                    "requests" : NumberLong(1),
                    "scanned" : NumberLong(0)
                }
            }
        },
        "ttl" : {
            "deletedDocuments" : NumberLong(0),
            "passes" : NumberLong(59)
        }
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: From `free -m` I can see that you're nearing 80% of your RAM. That may be why - physically, your computer is running out of memory to allocate.

Comment: was there any extra information in the log? `Assertion: 13636:file /data/db/project.6 open/create failed in createPrivateMap (look in log for more information)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After increasing ram the problem disappeared.
It will probably reoccur at some point.
At least now I know that in case of problems with MongoDB it is hard to find answers even at stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're currently capped at `1024` open files.  Although there's usually a boost error to accompany that kind of failure, it's worth trying something like `ulimit -n 4096`

see the docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/ulimit/

Comment: I posted the contents of the log along with the question, it is not useful. Most of the time I have no control over the server setup, things like ram etc. I knew MongoDB likes lots of ram, I didn't know that it will actually fail in case of ram shortage.